# IIS 7: Redirecting from non existing subdomains to a subfolder

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc, multi-tenancy

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC Multi Tenancy app.

Right now I managed to create dynamic subfolders, for instance some one registers with username "bob" and gets the following website:

domain.com/bob

My next goal is to provide subdomains: bob.domain.com instead of subfolders.

I found out that it's very complex to create dynamic subdomains with ASP.NET and DNS WMI. Is there a way to tell the server that it has to redirect/rewrite from bob.domain.com to domain.com/bob ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a wildcard entry for *.domain.com so that you don't need to create a DNS entry on every new account.

You can add a wildcard IIS binding too so that everything for a particular IP will bind to that site.  That you don't need to add tons of host headers in real-time.

URL Rewrite is one option for doing what you requested.  You can watch for {HTTP_HOST} with the pattern of ^(^.)+.domain.com$.  That will get everything.domain.com with a back reference of C:1.

Or, another option is to just check for Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"] from MVC directly.  You have full access to the domain name from code, so you have a lot of flexibility there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

The problem is when I create the *.domain.com entry in DNS server, I still can't access random.domain.com (subdomain that doesn't exist). I get no server found error, so I can't use Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"].

Comment: Never mind, I just had to add *.domain.com binding in IIS.

Thanks!

Comment: Excellent, glad you got it working.